# Python sqlite operation,SQL statement 'where field in (1,2)' syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Python sqlite operation,SQL statement 'where field in (1,2)' syntax error

The error is:`sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":id": syntax error`

My search of the Official Python documentation and Google failed to find the answer:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

How should arguments be passed?

```py
'''first create test.db:table and field
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
    id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    test_num   INT,
    test_field TEXT
);
'''

import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
con.set_trace_callback(print)  # start the debug
d = [
    (111,'aaa'),
    (111,'bbb'),
    (111,'ccc'),
    (444,'ddd')
]
sql = "insert into `test_tab` (`test_num`, `test_field`) values (?,?)"
cursor = con.executemany(sql, d)
con.commit()  # Execute successfully

#####################

# wrong code begin,why sql 'in ()' is wrong?
sql = "SELECT * from `test_tab` where `test_num`=:num AND `id` in :id"
par = {'num': 111, 'id': (1,2)}  # The number of 'id' parameters is uncertain
x = con.execute(sql, par)
print(x.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second query, you would need actually separate placeholders for every value in the `IN` clause.  In addition, I would use `?` here:

```py
num = 111
ids = (1, 2)
par = (num,) + ids
sql = "select * from test_tab where test_num = ? AND id in "
in_clause = '(?' + ', ?'*(len(ids) - 1) + ')'
sql = sql + in_clause
x = con.execute(sql, par)
print(x.fetchall())
```

The SQL query generated by the above script is:

```
select * from test_tab where test_num = ? AND in (?, ?)
```

and we bind `(111, 1, 2)` to the three `?` placeholders.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it's so clumsy, is it the only way?
I don't understand why tuples aren't officially supported, it's very clean.

Comment: At the end of the day, a prepared statement needs a separate `?` placeholder for every bound value; there is no way around this.  You could place some of my logic into a helper function and then just call it.

Comment: Thank a lot,i know it.

Comment: Maybe `join` inside an f-string: `in_clause = f"({', '.join('?' for _ in ids)})"`?

Comment: @parfait,This is essentially the same as the code above,It's all concatenated strings, but it does look better